# Camera layout bug

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera, barcode-scanner

I'm using a barcode scanner library wich uses a camera layout, the usual. I tried the library on three devices and it looks fine in all of them.

[image]

But in the fourth device, it looks like this.

[image]

I uploaded pictures instead screenshots because, when you make one, the bug doesn't appears on it. It just looks normal. This makes me think about some kind of GPU/Android bug or something like that, but I really don't know where this is coming from and how to fix it.

By the way, the devices I used testing are: Nexus 5 (6.0.1), Galaxy Young (4.1.2) and Doogee DG685 (4.2.2). In all of them the layout is perfectly showed. The bug only appears on a HoneyWell E70 (4.0.3).

Comment: The version is too old, so that is the probable cause. You will have to look through the library source files where they draw the camera layout. Btw what is the library name?

Comment: @MikhailKim the library is zxing-android-embedded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author has explained to me that it's caused by using **SurfaceView** instead of **SurfaceTexture**.

The library has a XML attribute to fix it:

```
app:zxing_use_texture_view="true"
```

But it's not documented. In the next release this option will be true by default.

Comment: Nice, you should accept your own answer if it resolved your issue.

Comment: @Marko I need to wait two days :)